# Are all countable sets of real numbers Borel sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A set is "Borel" if it can be formed from open (or closed) sets through the operations of countable union, countable intersection or relative complement.

I have the set A = $\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ...\}$

This is certainly a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and it can be formed from open sets of the form $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$):

A = $[\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})]^c$

But this is just one particular case.  I'm fairly certain it would be true in general, for all countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not sure how to tackle a general proof here.

Comment: A countable set is the countable union of its singletons, which are closed.

Answer (score 2):

Any countable set is indeed Borel, since such a set is $F_\sigma$, that is, a countable union of closed sets ($X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ is always true, and if $X$ is countable, this is a countable union). Moreover, this is optimal: there are countable sets which are **not** $G_\delta$, such as the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. (The standard tool here is the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).)